# Where is all the documentation for predictive intelligence on marketing cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud

Does anyone  have any idea where all the documentation been moved on for predictive intelligence? Eager to find out more and cant seem to locate it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find it under the [Personalization Builder](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/personalization_builder/) documentation:

- [Predictive Recommendations for Email](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/personalization_builder/predictive_email/)
- [Predictive Recommendations for Web](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/personalization_builder/predictive_web/)